# Sort fields list in Power BI desktop

Tags: sorting, powerbi-desktop, fieldlist

I need to sort a very long list fields in Power BI that I need in a special order - not the default sort by name/number.

My dataset looks like this:

[image]

and I created another table to use for sorting:

[image]

I am stuck from here. I think I need to create a relation between the to tables and then use it to sort the field list. But I do not know where to start.

The order I have now looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're sorting in Power Query, then:

1 Sort table `SortOrder` by column `SortOrder`:

```
= Table.Sort(#"Previous Step",{{"SortOrder", Order.Ascending}})
```

2 Sort table `Data` by list `SortOrder[ColumnName]`:

```
= Table.Sort(#"Previous Step",SortOrder[ColumnName])
```

### EDIT

It seems you're actually asking how to change the order in which fields are displayed in the `Fields Pane`

This is currently not possible - fields are always displayed in alphabetical order.

You may vote for this feature request: https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas/suggestions/18355429-use-field-order-as-ordered-in-source-query

The only workaround just now would be to rename your fields so they display in your required order - eg:

```
01_ClmName_A
02_ClmName_C
03_ClmName_E
04_ClmName_B
05_ClmName_Q
06_ClmName_F
```

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by Power Query. I added a screenshot from the desktop that shows the order I get. I need it order in a specific order because in my specific case I have 500 fields I need to choose from and I cannot remember all the names.

Comment: Added a screenshot of the list I would like to be sorted.

Comment: Updated answer, with your clarified requirement!

Comment: Exactly. I voted and crossed my fingers that they will make this feature soon.